# AlertDialog with a list shows empty dialog

Tags: android, view, android-arrayadapter, android-alertdialog

In my Android app I have a dialog that supposed to show a list:

```
final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(HomeActivity.this);
builder.setTitle("Pick a branch to navigate to:");
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
adapter.addAll(branches);
builder.setAdapter(adapter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        Intent searchAddress = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("geo:0,0?q=" + branches.toArray()[which]));
        startActivity(searchAddress);
    }
});
builder.show();
```

When I launch this code, I get a dialog with the title, and blank space below, but when I click the blank space it does the action and uses what it got right, so something wrong with the view.

What can I do with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your onClick actions doing fine it means that List filled properly only problem  with showing views. So check out your adapter class.

**EDIT:**
Change Application Context to Activity's Context

Comment: I've wrote on the question itself, that I suspect that something is wrong with the view, so if you can help me please.

Comment: Oh, so try to create custom adapter

Comment: But I don't think it should be that complicated. It just supposed to show a list of 3 or 4 items and that's it.

Comment: @Ido well everything looks fine .try to use activity context instead of Application one.

Comment: @Ido no problem :)